# Search programmatically if name contains a pattern in AWS SSM parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I'm looking for a programmatic way to retrieve parameters just by giving the name or a part of the complete path (instead of giving the full path with the name).

It's pretty easy using the Parameter Store AWS Systems Manager [console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/parameters), if I type `tokens`, I retrieve all parameters where the Name contains `tokens` :

[image: tokens_search]

Is there a way to do the same but using AWS CLI or AWS SDK (python or Go preferably) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or with Python:

```
import boto3

response = boto3.client("ssm").describe_parameters(
    ParameterFilters=[
        {
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Option': 'Contains',
            'Values': [
                'token',
            ]
        },
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are after:

```
aws ssm describe-parameters --parameter-filters Key=Name,Values=token,Option=Contains
```

Comment: Thanks, I accept the python example answer but yours is completely valid.

Comment: @NicolasPepinster No problem. Glad it worked out either way:-)